# vtune with mingw

Tags: optimization, gcc, mingw, profile, intel-vtune

I am trying to use vtune with my application compiled with mingw in Windows.
When I try to see souce code information, vtune says the is not line information in the resulting executable. I am compiling with -g option so I dont know where is the problem. So the questions are:

- Is it possible to profile with a program compiled with mingw in windows? It looks like all is ready for MS-VC, but not for mingw.
- If so, is it needed to change the object format (coff, xcoff, DWARF, ....)?
  maybe if someone post an example it would be valuable.

Answer (score 3):

Solved, compiled with

> -gstabs -g3

Comment: @shellter, while accepting your own answer is a Good Thing when you've solved your own question, you cannot award yourself rep.

Comment: @Kristo : Thanks for the clarification. I thought I had seen it happen on other questions.